# Apache mod_proxy proxyPass order of matching

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

If i have two rules for proxying and they 'overlap', is there a way to specify the most important rule?

Example (part of virtual host def.)

```
ProxyPass /foo http://bar:8180/
ProxyPass / http://bar:8181/
```

Here all traffic will be proxied to `http://bar:8181/`, because it matches the url first.

Is there a way to make `/foo/index.html` go to `http://bar:8180` (order or similar on the proxypass matching)?

Comment: I'd suggest using a `RewriteRule` with the `[P]` flag for complex proxy rules / exceptions

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of [mod_proxy/2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) say:

> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the
>   order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins.

So, perhaps your first rule won't match because of a missing trailing slash (after foo):

```
ProxyPass /foo/ http://bar:8180/
```